# Cannot get devise_oauth2_canvas_facebook to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting a "TypeError in Devise::FacebookConsumersController#callback: can't convert Hash into Integer" when I try to authenticate using Devise and devise_oauth2_canvas_facebook gem with the new Facebook API. Any ideas what can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It look like mooktakim the creator of the devise_oauth2_canvas_facebook gem is not updating it anymore. 
Here is his message on a pull request to that effect:
https://github.com/mooktakim/devise_oauth2_facebook/pull/9

He says that he is moving to Omnisocial
https://github.com/icelab/omnisocial#readme

This uses Omniauth which allows you to use logins from many different sources.
It might be better for you to move to Omniauth.